# Multivariate multiple regression validation

Tags: regression, multivariate-analysis

In `R`, I'm running a linear model of the form:

```
fit <- lm(cbind(Y1,Y2,Y2) ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data=regression_table);
```

Then I'm using predict to generate predictions;

```
predicted_vals <- predict(fit, test_data);
```

Does any one have suggestions on how I should go about evaluating the training error of this multivariate model? I understand the notion of cross validation for univariate multiple models, though I'm not sure how to go about go about doing something similar for a multivariate model.

Comment: This depends on the dependence between **observations** $i$ and $j$. E.g., if the observations are **independent**, then conceptually this is not different from validating a univariate model. Some info on this aspect of your model are appreciated.

Comment: Sure, observations are independent. It's probe based gene expression data, where X & Y are probes said to be independent measurements for different genes. Does this help?

Comment: You mentioned training error. Isn't that just the sum of residuals for your model on the data set that you used to create the model? In your question it looks like you used a new test set to make prediction, but that's not training error. Can you make prediction with your original training data set? There are lots of R function that can do that for you!

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a statistician, so, for me, your response is as cryptic as my problem. No offense intended.

Comment: @MartinForde my answer is correct. But if you are just looking for R code, that is off topic here. This forum is more about talking about statistics than sharing R code. Stackoverflow people can    Help u

Comment: No, that wasn't my question. I asked for help with a problem I've been working on for the past 3 days. "There are lots of R function that can do that for you!" is not an answer to my question, plus stackoverflow is for coding, not stats.

Comment: You answered a question with a question. I'm not a statistician, and I'm certainly not a mind reader. Something that might be obvious to you, is not to me. Sorry.

Comment: @MartinForde your problem is simple if you understand the statistics. However I think you are looking for just R code that you can copy and paste, that's for stsckoverflow.

Comment: well the problem might be simple for ... statisticians ... again... im not a statistician. that's why im asking statisticians... super simple stuff, right? i don't need you to write code for me, i'm looking for a way to understand what I'm dealing with and figure out my problem.