# Multiple repression training error

Tags: multiple-regression, linear

In R, I'm running a linear model of the form:

```
fit <- lm(cbind(Y1,Y2,Y2) ~ X1 + X2 + X3, data=regression_table);
predicted_vals <- predict(fit, test_data);
```

Does any one have suggestions on how I should go about evaluating the training error of this multivariate model? Observations are independent, and I understand how to go about doing cross validations for univariate  models, however there's no inherent function within R (to my knowledge) which handles MLM objects for this purpose.

Comment: This is a copy of http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235410/multivariate-multiple-regression-validation